# divs overlap eachother when zoomin in IE and Firefox, Chrome is ok

Tags: css, html

Am trying to prepare the divs so that I can insert content and style them, However when zooming within Firefox and IR the DIVS go on eachother and overlap. Can you explain what needs to be done as there are many different but confusing solutions which did not work in my case.

Thanks

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>My Website</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<link href="../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</head>

<body>
<div id = "container">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="../about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="../hobbies.php">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id = "container1">

  container1
  </div>

  <div id = "container2">
  container 2

  </div>
    <div id = "container3">
  container 3

 </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 /* CSS Document */

body {

    margin: 0px;


}

#container {

position:relative;
min-height: 800px;
margin:5%;  
background-color:#FFC;
height: 100%;
width: 90%;
overflow: hidden;


}

#container1 {


position:absolute;
margin-left: 10%;   
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: 10%;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#6FA;
height: 30%;
width: 80%;


}

#container2 {


position:absolute;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-top: 45%;
background-color:#09C;
overflow: hidden;
height: 30%;
width: 37%;
float:left;


}

#container3 {


position:absolute;
margin-left: 53%;
margin-top: 45%;
margin-right: 10%;
background-color:#6FE;
overflow: hidden;
height: 30%;
width: 37%;
float:right;


}



#nav  {

width: 750px;
margin-left: 10%;   
padding: 0%;
list-style:none;


}

#nav li {

    float:left;

}

#nav a {

    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    width:150px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#DBDBDB;
    color:#03F;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using absolute positioning with margin settings that work with `%`s, you're going to almost inevitably run into some overlapping or layout issues as depending on the screen size of the user and what zoom level they're at your format can be wildly different. A more usual approach is to design your page at a certain size using margin `%`s sparingly, if at all. While or after building you can zoom in and out and ensure that the format stays as you wanted it.

That being said, I did go through your HTML and CSS a bit and added wrappers for your header and content sections, then made the containers positioned relative. I kept in all the margin `%`s as you had it and it's much more stable and works on Firefox as well (unless you zoom out so much that nothing would be even remotely legible anyway).

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xCTcW/4/)

Comment: So should all containers be set with a certain size in px instead of percentage and did not really understand why you have created the wrappers. Is this a best practice ?

Comment: I have done some further changes, hope it is fine and please let me know as I still need to understand abourt how these wrappers and absolute vs relative are all used together. http://jsfiddle.net/XVpUC/ PS> Ignore the navigation bar as I am concentrating on the Divs positioning

Comment: If you use a wrapper then you can layout the main blocks of elements using relative positioning and then absolute position the minor ones against the wrapper instead of against the overall page. That way when you zoom in and out the layout can respond better - you get the best of both worlds.

On the pixels vs %s, use what you like and what works best for your project. In general most people prefer pixels, but that's a person decision.

Your fiddle looks good and it looks like that solved what you were running into.